# Analyzing a OSx UI Application in Valgrind

Tags: macos, debugging, valgrind

I am new to OSX development, I had a question regarding running valgrind 3.6.1 on mac osx : 10.6.8

I was trying to analyze a GUI application using valgrind; However, From a console the GUI application cannot be directly launched and can be launched as: `open MyApplication.app`  So to check this application with valgrind, I executed, `valgrind --trace-children=yes open MyApplication.app` but still I couldn't get valgrind to analyze the application. (Could get the logs only for the `open` command) I am new to Mac OSx and may be missing something obvious, could somebody pls point out how we can analyze a UI application in valgrind on Mac? The `MyApplication.app` is shown as a executable when seen from Mac's finder.
Thanks. (Posting it here since I am yet to get a response on the mailing list)

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there something you use in Valgrind that’s not available in Instruments?

Comment: The application binary is inside the app bundle and can in fact be run from the command line.

Comment: @Bavarious: Thanks for pointing me to instruments, will take a look at it. I am more of *nix developer and my affinity towards valgrind springs from this background  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution, we can analyze the application as follows: `valgrind MyApplication.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApplication`

MyApplication.app is basically a folder, which contains the executable and other resources.

Comment: Mac apps are a special kind of folder called an "application bundle".

Comment: Did it work out? Have the same problem but can't figure out - almost lost hope - could you help with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41581857/valgrind-doesnt-show-ui-of-application

Comment: @htzfun I had tried looong back, from what I remember the effort was not fruitful and I abandoned it. Its better to use XCode provided tools instead.